# Detecting certain strings within a given answer string

Tags: regex, google-forms

What am I doing wrong with Google Form response validation regex?

I need a regex to work within Google Forms that will pass if at least one of a list of strings is detected within the answer given by a user.

For example, with this regex expression:
`.+(HEri|Gu8m|sm8p|sRVV|s7ST|k0it|gZLu|bRkJ|xouE|23nK).+`

As long as one of the phrases from above: `HEri`, `Gu8m`, `sm8p`, or etc. is detected in the provided string we want it to pass.

So, for example, this answer should work because `sm8p` is in the string.
`JFSyr34sm8p1aDqFP5CL`

Here's Google's documentation about their regex: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en

Here is a toy example Google form you can play with: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rz00ddsGw5oWAgPkgXGcVczE5YcHOkYx56TEsr1vj00/edit

[Here's an example of a regex I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xYZa.png)

When I enter in `JFSyr34sm8p1aDqFP5CL` as the answer, it doesn't take it. See below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h0j6.png)

Any help is appreciated!

I've tried using `Contains` and `Matches` and altering the regex accordingly, but haven't found a combo that works.

Here's the regex expression that should work:

```
.+(HEri|Gu8m|sm8p|sRVV|s7ST|k0it|gZLu|bRkJ|xouE|23nK).+
```

So, for example, this answer should work:
`JFSyr34sm8p1aDqFP5CL`

but this or any number of other strings as an answer shouldn't work:

`JFSyr341aDqFP5CL1234`

Answer (score 0):

So response validation doesn't work as I expected. I thought I could use it to either give students points or not based on their answer but instead response validation only lets students put in certain answers and doesn't have to do with grading. :(